# How perform a Subtraction between matrix Matlab. Aerospace

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, subtraction

Hi i need to perform in matlab a subtraction between a matrix and a row vector.
I am working on a university project in which we assume an airplane explosion resulting in the generation of debris. for conservation of momentum, momentum must remain the same after the explosion.
Being that I generate the debris and its velocity increments randomly, there is an error in momentum , which I am trying to remove.
The result I get is close to zero. But for physics , it has to be zero.
I think I am doing some steps wrong in the operations between matrices and vectors

```
Mv=10000; 
V_0 = 200*.3048; 

N=1000
D=rand(N,1); 
somma=sum(D); 
m_i=(D/somma)*Mv; %mass of debris
ver=sum(m_i); 

vx_i = randn(N,1);
vy_i = randn(N,1); 
vz_i= randn(N,1);

DeltaV_iStar= [vx_i,vy_i,vz_i]; % i-esima velocity matrix 



DeltaQ_err=zeros(1,3);
DeltaQ=zeros(N,3); %inizializzo matrice 
for k=1:N
  DeltaQ(k,:)=(m_i(k)*DeltaV_iStar(k,:));  
  DeltaQ_err=DeltaQ_err+DeltaQ(k,:);
end
DeltaQ_err % momentun 


DeltaV_err = DeltaQ_err/Mv ; % errore da togliere agli incrementi iniziali

**DeltaV_c(:,3) = DeltaV_iStar(:,3) - DeltaV_err(1);** %i-esima matrix velocity which has been corrected

%% Now i do the same thing but with the correct value of velocity to verify that the momentum is zero

DeltaQ_err2=zeros(1,3);
DeltaQ=zeros(N,3); %inizializzo matrice 
for k=1:N
  DeltaQ(k,:)=(m_i(k)*DeltaV_c(k,:));  
  DeltaQ_err2=DeltaQ_err2+DeltaQ(k,:);
end
DeltaQ_err2 % momentum that must be zero
```

Comment: I’m not sure how your title and question body are related to the code you post. But have you tried just directly subtracting the vector from the matrix? `A-B`

Comment: Yes, and it's not working

Comment: What is the error you see? Print the size of matrices you want to subtract just to see if it make sense to do broadcasting or subtract. You could use breakpoints or print to debug your code and solve the problem. This way you could understand the underlying logics of the operation

Comment: What does `DeltaV_err(1,)` mean? Are you subtracting floating-point values? Then they probably won't come out to exactly 0. Please post sample input, output, and your expected results.

Comment: “It’s not working” is not useful feedback. Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly. Currently, it is unclear what the code attempts to do, or how it relates to the question. Copy-paste your error messages, or your actual output compared to your expected output, into your question.

Comment: Update:  I have tried to explain in a few words what I want to achieve.                                              Here the resulta of my code:                                                                          
DeltaQ_err2 =

   1.0e-12 *

   -0.0577    0.2274   -0.0817                                                                                                                   but must be '0 0 0'

Comment: Please add updates and clarifications to the body of your question using [edit], not as a comment. You're running into the limitations of floating-point precision. -0.0577 x 10^-12 is effectively zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is only condtion in the matrix subtraction, dimension must match.
lets say a(n,m) and b(n,m);
then you can directly write in matlab like: a-b;
you will get result.